# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Tags: php, arrays, time

I'm not very good with arrays, but I'm trying. Can't figure this one out though. I would like to make this script, echo out `$text2`, in the end of each "numberofunits", if the units is above 1. It's danish.

år is year,
måned is month,
uge is week,
etc. etc.

```
function humanTiming ($time)
{

    $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
    $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'år' => '',
        2592000 => 'måned' => 'er',
        604800 => 'uge' => 'r',
        86400 => 'dag' => 'e',
        3600 => 'time' => 'r',
        60 => 'minut' => 'ter',
        1 => 'sekund' => 'er'
    );

    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text => $text2) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
        $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
        return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'.$text2.':'');
    }

}

$time = $row['timestamp'];
echo humanTiming($time);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP multi-dimensional arrays don't work this way,

```
$tokens = [
    31536000 => 'år' => '',
];
```

do it this way:

```
$tokens = [
    31536000 => ['år' => ''],
    2592000 => ['måned' => 'er'],
];
```

(`[ ]` is an array notation which can be used since PHP 5.4, if you have earlier versions, use `array( )` instead.)

Although I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need..

When you have a specific type of array, you should try using objects. They look more difficult first, but they are easier for real (compared to C++ `struct` maybe).

Answer to comment, loop `foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text => $text2)` doesn't work:

You can't loop over a **multi**dimensional array that easy.
You need **2 nested foreach**:

```
foreach ($tokens as $token => $unitArray) { // outer array
    echo $token, PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($unitArray as $unit => $text) { // inner array
        echo $unit . ' has text: ' . $text, PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Parameter syntax:

```
foreach ($array as $value)
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Don't get confused by what is key and what is value, value is **always** the variable you assigned (to the key), no matter what type of variable. If you don't specify a key, it's automatically a numeric array starting by `0`.

Comment: I'm sure that this is what I'm looking for. I will look into objects! Thank you. I get the same error for this line now: 

foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text => $text2) {

How can I fix this one?

Comment: @Morten Same as before :) Do not chain `=>` operators, but like nested arrays in Dan's answer, use nested foreach.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much - it's working like a charm!

@MorganTouvereyQuilling - thank you :)